# LaTeX 'Cannot execute this comand'

Tags: errors, compiling, windows, texniccenter

working first time with TeX, installed TexNicCenter and MikTeX. I got some .tex files which I want to convert to .pdf just to make sure everything is installed properly and it works so I can stark working on the TeX thing.

Problem: I chose Latex -> Pdf as my profile and entered each option as told by my professor in his screenshot.

LatexCompiler: `C:\Program Files\Miktex\miktex\bin\pdflatex.exe`
Arguments for the compiler: `-interaction=nonstopmode -max-print-line=120"%wm"`

BibTex Compiler: `C:\Program Files\Miktex\miktex\bin\bibtex.exe`
Arguments: "%bm"

MakeIndex Compiler: `C:\Program Files\Miktex\miktex\bin\makeindex.exe`
Arguments: "%bm"

When using this profile on an existing .tex file this happens: Adobe Reader opens, says he couldn't find the selected file, another error occurs stating that it wasn't possible to execute the command "%bm". Yes I googled for that (http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=6897), but those solutions don't help me. Also, in the ouptut-log box in the bottom of texniccenter it says, that there are 0 error and 0 warnings. However it also says, **that pdflatex has a bad file descriptor and bibxtex and makeindex couldn't open their needed .aux and .idx files**.

What can I do here to make the given .tex files run properly?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

I know this may not be the solution you're looking for, but you might want to try TeXworks, it's got a built-in pdf reader, so you can see right away if your file generated. That way you'll know if the problem is your compiler, or your tex editor or your adobe.